# Array issue pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need the following code to store the profitability of each month in an array for later display in a table.

```
profits_jan = array.new_float(5)
for int j = 0 to 4 
    var jan_0 = timestamp(2019 + j  ,1 ,1)
    var jan_1 = timestamp(2019 + j ,1 ,31)
    if time >= jan_0 and time <= jan_1 
        array.push(profits_jan, math.round(strategy.netprofit/strategy.initial_capital * 100,2)) 
    table.cell(performance, column = 1, row = 1 + j , text = str.tostring(array.get(profits_jan,j)) + "%", text_color=color.white)
```

I tried this, and the table looks like this.It should display the monthly profitability for January over the 5 years.

[image]

I can't understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

array.set instead of push
and you can use  [log.info](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-logs-in-pine-script-40490/) to see what's wrong

```
profits_jan = array.new_float(5, na)
for int j = 0 to 4 
    var jan_0 = timestamp(2019 + j  ,1 ,1)
    var jan_1 = timestamp(2019 + j ,1 ,31)
    if time >= jan_0 and time <= jan_1 
        array.set(profits_jan, j, math.round(strategy.netprofit/strategy.initial_capital * 100,2))
        // log.info( str.tostring(profits_jan))
        table.cell(performance, column = 0, row = 0 + j , text = str.tostring(array.get(profits_jan,j)) + "%", text_color=color.white)
```